# How to not loose selection when click on input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the `textarea` and the input below it. When I select some text from `textarea` and click on the `input`, then my selection disappears. How can I make it still visible?

```
<textarea style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
  Test data
</textarea>

<input> </input>
```

```html
<textarea style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
  Test data
</textarea>

<input> </input>
```

Comment: What are you running this on? This doesn't seem to be a problem on my web browser.

Comment: look at my attached code snippet (post edited). Seleciting text and then clicking on the input removes the selection. Your answer provide solution for button, not input. How to make it work?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, and still, on my device the text-area doesn't have its content deleted. What device are you using.

Comment: Could you give the full code? It might me something in the javascript that's making it disappear. Or it could be CSS, but either way, give us the full code so we don't have to guess what is happening

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the selection and restore it (on `blur` and `focus`).

```js
let selectionStart = 0;
let selectionEnd = 0;

textarea.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  selectionStart = textarea.selectionStart;
  selectionEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;
});

textarea.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  textarea.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
})

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("click");
  textarea.focus();
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">make a selection the click button </textarea>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Comment: look at my attached code snippet (post edited). Seleciting text and then clicking on the input removes the selection. Your answer provide solution for button, not input. How to make it work?

Comment: I don't think that is possible since you can only have 1 selection on page, and when  you focus another input you are de-facto creating another selection.

Answer (score 0):

Copied everything you provided into a HTML editor and I didn't run into this issue. If this is all you've got, you need to put it into the body or a header or something, but if you have more code written your issue is more than likely in there.

Comment: look at my attached code snippet (post edited). Seleciting text and then clicking on the input removes the selection. How to make it work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).